# .NET SOAP 1.2 - Envelope Version

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

How can I change s:Envelope to soap12:Envelope format?

Request Headers:
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1251

I am getting a server error.

I tried using Postman, it was working there when I send:
`<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">`

However, I am using this .NET code and it's returning:
`<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">`

The .NET Code:
`System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding result = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(); System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(); textBindingElement.MessageVersion = System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.CreateVersion(System.ServiceModel.EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressingVersion.WSAddressing10); result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement); System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement(); httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = true; httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue; httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue; result.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement); return result;`

Answer (score 0):

To change .Net soap 1.2 version you need to have a soap 1.2 request with headers and envelope. [The case](https://docs.informatica.com/data-as-a-service/address-verification-(cloud)/4-0/developer-guide/informatica-address-verification-interface/soap-1-2-headers-and-envelope.html) shows an example about it.